# Stop page from jumping back to the top

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1

I have a datagrid which works fine, but I've had complaints from users that when they click on datagrid rows (which expands the row to show more info about that they clicked on), the page jumps back to the top of the page, meaning, they have to scroll back down to see the expanded details of the row they clicked on.

How do I stop that from happening?

I have added `smartnavigation=true` to the top tag of the problem page, i.e.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Explicit="true" Strict="false" EnableSessionState="True" smartnavigation="True" %>
```

I am using .NET 1.1 code on a server which has got .NET 2.0 installed.  I'm assuming .NET 2.0 is backwards compatible with .NET 1.1 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you mention is deprecated in ASP2.0 but should likely work anyway. The problem could be that a modern web browser have dropped the compability-mode for IE6 and below.

Which version of the browser do your users have? .NET1.1 seems very outdated, and there have been a lot of change in how the browsers work...

Comment: OK, can you just try to update your code to SmartNavigation="True" (mind the casing) so we rule that one out? :)

Answer (score -1):

put

```
return false;
```

after function in onclick